# How to get retrofit response in kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to parse json using retrofit, but this is the first time i'm using retrofit

this is the json looks like

```
    {
    "results": [
        {
            "idEvent": "576561",
            "idSoccerXML": "389946",
            "strEvent": "Liverpool vs Cardiff",
            "strFilename": "English Premier League 2018-10-27 Liverpool vs Cardiff",
            "strSport": "Soccer",
            "idLeague": "4328",
            "strLeague": "English Premier League",
            "strSeason": "1819",
            "strDescriptionEN": null,
            "strHomeTeam": "Liverpool",
            "strAwayTeam": "Cardiff",
            "intHomeScore": "4",
            "intRound": "10",
            "intAwayScore": "1",
        },
     {.
      .  
      .
}]
```

i'm using retrofit to get the data.
this is my interface

```
interface INetworkAPI {

@GET("api/v1/json/1/eventslast.php?id=133602")
fun getAllPosts(): Call<Team>
```

}

and this is where i trying to callback but i don't really understand

```
rv__list_posts?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.requireContext())

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://www.thesportsdb.com/").build()

    val postsApi = retrofit.create(INetworkAPI::class.java)

    var response = postsApi.getAllPosts()

    response.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(IoScheduler()).subscribe {
        rv__list_posts.adapter = MainAdapter(it, this.requireContext())
    }
```

i don't know how to callback it in the good way and it still error becaouse it still using observeOn.
please help me if you know

Comment: *"it still error"* What error?

Comment: because it using `observeOn` it must be not use that. i was follow this tutorial http://developine.com/kotlin-android-json-parsing-tutorial-retrofit/ but the json not like me so it must change the interface and i don't know how to get the response after that

Answer (score 0):

Example on Java:

**JSON**

```
{
        "employeeList": [
        {
            "name": "Gretchen Rodriquez",
            "email": "gretchenrodriquez@trasola.com",
            "phone": "6204732096"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sharon Harris",
            "email": "sharonharris@trasola.com",
            "phone": "2184582386"
        },
        {
            "name": "Serrano Haynes",
            "email": "serranohaynes@trasola.com",
            "phone": "1434162816"
        },
        {
            "name": "Wagner Thornton",
            "email": "wagnerthornton@trasola.com",
            "phone": "5494622467"
        },
        {
            "name": "Mooney Dawson",
            "email": "mooneydawson@trasola.com",
            "phone": "3894433413"
        }
        ]
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public class Employee {
        @SerializedName("name")
        private String name;
        @SerializedName("email")
        private String email;
        @SerializedName("phone")
        private String phone;

        public Employee(String name, String email, String phone) {
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
            this.phone = phone;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }

        public void setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }
}
```

**LIST**

```
public class EmployeeList {
        @SerializedName("employeeList")
        private ArrayList<Employee> employeeList;

        public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployeeArrayList() {
            return employeeList;
        }

        public void setEmployeeArrayList(ArrayList<Employee> employeeArrayList) {
            this.employeeList = employeeArrayList;
        }
}
```

More: https://medium.com/@jacinth9/android-retrofit-2-0-tutorial-89de3c714c63